# Problema no require

Tags: php

Esta mensagem de erro esta me aparecendo, não sei como solucionar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Erro de caminho errado

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `usuario_class.php`, na linha 2, troque `require "../core/conecta.php"` por `require __FILE__ . "/../core/conecta.php"`.

Basicamente a constante `__FILE__` retorna o diretorio do arquivo onde foi declarada (e não do arquivo onde foi incluida) que nesse caso seria `exemplo_2/class`. Ai o require ficaria similar a `require "exemplo_2/class/../core/conecta.php"`. Ou seja a partir da pasta `class` seria subido um diretorio (ficaria dentro da pasta exemplo_2), e seria possivel acessar a pasta core.

O mesmo não acontece no require original (`require "../core/conecta.php"`), pois os caminhos relativos são feitos em relação ao arquivo `index.php` (que foi quem incluiu o arquivo `usuario_class.php`). Nesse caso, ao interpretar o require ficaria `require "exemplo_2/../core/conecta.php"`. Ou seja, nessa situação a pasta core deveria estar fora de exemplo_2.

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

Para evitar esses conflitos, utilize a informação do array do PHP: DOCUMENT_ROOT!
Está variável vai retornar o caminho principal do servidor WWW/HTDOCS/WEB

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$_DIR = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once "$_DIR/assets/server/configuration.php";
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado! ^.^

Answer (score -1):

é pra chamar outro arquivo certo ?

se for usa o require_once

```
require_once("arquivo_aqui");
```